# How to remove ALL kind of linebreaks or formattings from strings in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, strip

I know the classic way of dealing with linebreaks, tabs,.. is to .strip() or .remove('\n',''). 
But sometimes there are special cases in which these methods fail, e.g.

```
         'H\xf6cke\n\n:\n\nDie'.strip()

  gives: 'H\xf6cke\n\n:\n\nDie'
```

How can I catch these rare cases which would have to be covered one by one (e.g. by .remove('*', '')? The above is just one example I came across.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: That would be 'H\xf6cke:Die'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: text = 'H\xf6cke\n\n:\n\nDie'

In [3]: re.sub(r'\s+', '', text)
Out[3]: 'Höcke:Die'
```

**\s:**

> Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes [ \t\n\r\f\v],
>   and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces
>   mandated by typography rules in many languages). If the ASCII flag is
>   used, only [ \t\n\r\f\v] is matched (but the flag affects the entire
>   regular expression, so in such cases using an explicit [ \t\n\r\f\v]
>   may be a better choice).

**'+'**

> Causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the
>   preceding RE.

Comment: Great answer, because it takes care of many different forms of formatting that are reliably removed instead of adding a .remove('\*', '') for every type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` if you dont want to import anything

```
a = "H\xf6cke\n\n:\n\nDie"
print(a.replace("\n",""))

# Höcke:Die
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip's documentation:
Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
 whitespace removed.
 If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.

That's why it didn't remove the '\n' within the text.

If you want to remove the '\n' occurrences you can use

```
'H\xf6cke\n\n:\n\nDie'.replace('\n','')
Output: Höcke:Die
```